# FQL: list posts from stream table - how to exclude special post types?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

The simple query returns a list of recent posts:
SELECT post_id from stream where filter_key="nf"

I know, this query is useless - its only a example, but it works^^

I get the list of posts from groups, friends and posts made by me and things
like "User X has commented a photo". This table records are separated from the next following
post with the photo post. But, this following post wasn't made by a friend or a group where i'm a member but may be a "friend of a friend" or "liked page of my friend". I can read the photo data and can view the photo when its public - so at this point its not a problem.
The problem i have: i want to hide this following post (or dont get it with the request) when its not a content from my friends or groups, or if possible, show this post as in the facebook webpage like a "box in a box". Is this possible? I have tried to take this next post from the array while i loop through, but sometimes this post doesnt appears in the result list - so the bug is then, i exclude wanted posts.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks a lot :)